# Could you tell me whether this sentence is an inverted sentence?

Tags: inversion

I read a conversation in a IELTS listening test

> Oh, I see, and how long can I hang on to them for?

so, normally, it should be

> oh, I see, and how long can I hang on to for them?

Am I right?

Comment: I can't answer definitively whether this counts as an inversion or not, but I can tell you that the "for" is associated with the "how long". If you were to rearrange it, you would get _"for how long can I hang on to them?"_. I guess it is perhaps an inversion, because it is a question(?). The statement would be _"I can hang on to them for a week [or some other length of time]."_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a matter of inversion but of what linguists call "pied-piping" vs "stranding".

That is, the canonical declarative form which underlies your question is

```
                 I can hang on to them for [TIME EXPRESSION].
```

Note that *TIME EXPRESSION* is the complement of the preposition *for*. *For* is not related to *them*.

When you turn this into a question, you substitute the interrogative phrase *how long* for *[TIME EXPRESSION]* and move *how* and its complement to the front of the sentence, and you invert the subject *I* and the auxiliary *can*:

```
                I can hang on to them for [TIME EXPRESSION]. 
                 ⇘⇙                              ⇓
           ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  how long
         ⇓       ⇙⇘
       How long can I hang on to them for?
```

Note that *How long* is now separated from the preposition which governs it, *for*; *for* is said to be "stranded".  In formal writing it helps make the relationship clearer if you "pied-pipe" the preposition along with the interrogative, like this:

```
                I can hang on to them for [TIME EXPRESSION]. 
                 ⇘⇙                   ⇓          ⇓
           ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐for      how long
         ⇓       ⇙⇘
   For how long can I hang on to them?
```

So either of these constructions is correct:

> How long can I hang on to them for? *... is probably most common in speech*
>   For how long can I hang on to them? *... is preferred in the most formal writing.*

Comment: ... except that "hang on to" is not formal writing! Something like "how long can I keep/use/retain them" would be a better formal version - and doesn't need "for" at all.