# "whose foot you stepped on" — can I say "on whose foot you stepped"?

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses

I know the following is okay:

> 1. The child whose foot you stepped on is fine.

Can I also say this?

> 2. The child on whose foot you stepped is fine.

I know that we can place prepositions before *whom* and *which*, but is the second sentence acceptable too?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can say that. It doesn't matter which question word you are using. Here are a couple of examples from [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

> She wanted a guy **on whose** shoulder she would do the crying.
>
> Today, we are the legatees of all the giants **on whose** shoulders we stand.

As *CGEL* seems to suggest (see below), if a preposition isn't a part of a phrasal verb (a fixed combination of a verb and a preposition, such as *[tell on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell-on-sb)*), it can be either moved to the front of the clause or left at the end. The first phenomenon is called *[pied-piping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-piping)*; the second, *[preposition stranding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding)*. Both are well explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/127939/21520) and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14664/21520). Generally, it is more natural to leave the preposition at the end, especially in informal speech.

However, if a preposition *is* a part of a phrasal verb, whether it can be moved to the front depends on the verb. Here is what *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* says about it (Chapter 4, 6.1.1):

```
i  the city to which I flew   [relative]
ii To which city did you fly? [open interrogative]
```

> There are alternants with a stranded preposition (*the city which I flew to*, etc.).

*Fly to* isn't a phrasal verb: you can just as well *[fly through](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22through%20which%20*%20flew%22)* or *[fly into](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22into%20which%20*%20flew%22)* something.

> Consider now the behaviour of specified prepositions in these constructions, the mobile *to* selected by *refer* and the fixed *across* selected by *come*:

```
[6]        MOBILE PREPOSITION                  FIXED PREPOSITION
i   a. the book to which I referred    b. *the letters across which I came
ii  a. To which book did you refer?    b. *Across which letters did you come?
```

> *Across* cannot be moved to the left of *come*, so only the versions with stranded prepositions are admissible: *the letters which I came across; Which letters did you come across?*.

Both *refer to* and *come across* are phrasal verbs. The *to* in *refer to* is mobile whereas the *across* in *come across* is fixed.

This also applies to cases where a phrasal verb has a direct object (*me* in the examples below):

```
[12]      MOBILE PREPOSITION                        FIXED PREPOSITION
i   a. He referred me to a specialist.        b. He got me through the biology test.
ii  a. the specialist to whom he referred me  b. *the test through which he got me
iii a. To whom did he refer you?              b. *Through which test did he get you?
```

> The [b] examples contain the transitive idiom *get through*, “help pass”, and here the specified preposition *through* cannot be moved.